# Drag and Drop in select element (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem getting Drag and Drop for the option elements inside different select elements to work in Google Chrome.

Here is my JSFiddle (Works fine in Firefox):
http://jsfiddle.net/DyAXf/1/

and the code:

```
    <script>
    function allowDrop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev)
    {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <form>
                    <select id="taglist1" class="tagdiv" name="taglist1" size=7 ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <option id='giessen' class="dragElement" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="option1">giessen</option>
                        <option id='giessen2' class="dragElement" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="option2">giessen2</option>
                        <option id='giessen3' class="dragElement" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="option3">giessen3</option>
                        <option id='giessen4' class="dragElement" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="option4">giessen4</option>
                        <option id='giessen5' class="dragElement" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="option5">giessen5</option>
                        <option id='giessen6' class="dragElement" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="option6">giessen6</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="taglist2" class="tagdiv" name="taglist2" size=7 ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></select>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <form action="game.php" method="post">
                    <input class="uibutton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The reason I need the select elements is because I want to know which terms are in which select element after the form is fired.
It is some kind of sorting where I want to know which terms are stacked together. Is there a better solution to handle this? Is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a desirable answer, but it seems like google chrome has problems using the drag and drop on select items (works fine in Firefox). I worked around the problem bei using the jquery sortable interaction, while sending the information serialized through ajax post.

Comment: FYI I did file this as a bug with the Chromium project ~2 years ago (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=860040) but it has not been acted on yet.